# what is an aar in build.gradle file in an android project

Tags: android

I have a project containing a  **build.gradle** file in which i see the following lines :

```
dependencies {
    compile('to.talk.aragorn:exception-utils:0.1-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
```

I dont understand what does this means. what is **aar** ? How do i interpret **to.talk.aragorn:exception-utils:0.1-SNAPSHOT@aar** ? Also what does transitive means ?
Please suggest some good resources too for getting to know gradle better.

Thanks

Comment: Differences between a Project and a Library Project
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: "Please suggest some good resources..." : just use your favorite search engine, typing "gradle" and "aar android" should be a REALLY GREAT way to find some information !

Comment: .aar is the abbreviation of Android Application Library, and this is what you pack an android library. It is analogues with .jar libraries, but for android libraries that contain resourses. As others suggested, doing a simple google would reveal the answer to your question. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format